# Saving a matplotlib animation with imagemagick, and without ffmpeg or mencoder

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, imagemagick, sgi

I want to create an animation of a calculated function. I'm not able to install ffmpeg or mencoder on the cluster I'm using to run the animation, but imagemagick is installed. `matplotlib.animation` apparently supports imagemagick as a writer for animations (see [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.ImageMagickBase), for example). The documentation says that the supported formats are:

```
['png', 'jpeg', 'ppm', 'tiff', 'sgi', 'bmp', 'pbm', 'raw', 'rgba']
```

I recognize several of these as non-animated file types, but apparently ffmpeg supports `.sgi` files in some way. It's fine if the codec that I have to use on the cluseter is obscure if I can convert it on my home computer with ffmpeg or mencoder.

**How can I use imagemagick to save an animation with matplotlib?**

Comment: Is an animated gif acceptable?

Comment: @ebarr: Acceptable, but less than ideal.

Comment: Use the imagemagick writer that you link to.  I really don't understand your question as I think you link to the answer in it.

Comment: @tcaswell: According to the documentation, gif isn't a supported format.

Comment: At present matplotlib seems like it will default to using Pillow to make a gif if you don't specify `writer`. **And so you don't need imagemagick  or ffmpeg or mencoder.**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This old post popped up while I was struggling to get some `matplotlib` animations exported as an animated gif. It's not rocket science, but still somewhat of a hassle to set up the first time around. I'll leave this post for future reference.

As for the specifics when setting up this environment on a cluster, you'll have to translate each step for the specific needs for your server I guess. Animated gif is at least one of the animation options offered by the `ImageMagickWriter`, but there may be more.

### How-to

- Get the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) binaries
- Set an environment variable `MAGICK_HOME` pointing to the `'<your-install-dir>\modules\coders'` folder (see [the docs](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/install.html). When on windows, remember to log off and back on)
- point matplotlib to the install dir of ImageMagick: ([mpl docs on rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html))

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  plt.rcParams['animation.convert_path'] = '<your-install-dir>/magick.exe'
  ```
- Export your animation! ([mpl docs on `ImageMagickFileWriter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.ImageMagickFileWriter.html#matplotlib.animation.ImageMagickFileWriter))

  ```
  writer = ImageMagickFileWriter()
  your_animation.save('location.gif', writer=writer)
  ```

Note that by default, errors thrown by ImageMagick will not reach you, apart from a nonzero return code. To get more extensive feedback, you'll need something like

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.verbose.set_level("helpful")
```

### Bonus

As a bonus, here's a proof-of-life:

[image: Mother's age at first pregnancy in The Netherlands]

Comment: `mpl.verbose.set_level("helpful")` didn't work for me. Try `mpl.rcParams['verbose.level'] = 'helpful'`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can download  imagemagick and edit matplotlibrc to enable it

Comment: Can you provide more details?